# Access ngfor item dynamically by id from component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this list which is a little chat stream. As you can see I already tried using  `#messageList` and `[id]="msg.messageId"` but not with success :

```
 <div class="wrapping" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
    <ul #messageList>
      <li *ngFor="let msg of messages" [ngClass]="getClassPosition(msg)" [id]="msg.messageId">
        <div class="msg-content lighten-3 center-align" [ngClass]="getClassColor(msg)">
          <span class="msg-text">{{msg.messageContent}}</span>
          <div class="msg-loading-icon  right">
            <img class="msg-icon" src={{getMessageStateIcon(msg.state)}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <small class="grey-text">{{msg.sender}} • {{msg.sendedOn}}</small>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

In the component I have the ref of the list :

```
@ViewChild('messageList') messageList: ElementRef;
```

Each Message have it's own Id. When the user send a message I display it in the list.

The state is represented by `msg-icon`.

When receiving an event that changes the state of the message from `sent` to `read` for example, I would like to change this `msg-icon` to another icon for this message only.

I would like to do something like this (it's just an example just for the idea) :

```
this.messageList.toArray().nativeElement.byId(messageId).getImageChild().setSrc('/another/img')
```

How can I access a specific item in the list to update the image ?

Comment: Your method `getMessageStateIcon(msg.state)` does not work? Or is not called at the appropriate time?

Comment: To the method `getMessageStateIcon(msg.state)` msg.messageId aswell. This helps in identifying which stateicon should be changed. Then within your getMessageStateIcon method, update your message object using message ID.( only that message should be updated).

Comment: Why not give angular your new image source and update the message object appropriately?

Comment: The first time the list is loaded it define the state of the past messages, but for new messages I need to retreive the item from the list of element

Comment: @G_S can you elaborate your idea ?

Comment: If your new message is added to `messages`, the list should update automatically after change detection, and display the appropriate icon (and also update the icon when the state changes). It does not? You should not have to retrieve the HTML elements in code.

Comment: btw, where do you have the event? where it changes from sent to read?

Comment: I'm using socketio in a service, a method return an observable that is subscribed in the component. Each time the event `message` is received I call  obs.next(); to notify the component of the new message. There in the component I search for the message by it's id in the array and update it's state